# xamarin nuget packages not being found in references

Tags: visual-studio, firebase, xamarin.android, google-play, nuget

I am having a publishing a release build of my xamarin android app. I recently implemented firebase messenging along with the associated google play services and have all the latest nuget packages installed. However, I still have this showing in my visual studio references - 
[image: references]

I was dealing with the proguard issue, java.exe exited with error code 1 and added a proguard file with the following lines -

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; } 
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
```

This allowed the app to build but not it just hangs on the splash screen and doesn't goes dark.

Before I got this far I posted [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88980/issue-building-with-proguard-android-7#latest) while I was looking for ways to fix my proguard issue. Everything is peachy in a debug release mode but this release build is leaving me without many clues.

Comment: The references to a package might get broken within a Visual Studio project. Could you try to use the command in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console) to reinstall package: Update-Package –reinstall?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to make a difference. From what I've been reading, this normally comes up when dealing with different .Net versions but I don't see how that applies to the xamarin android project as there is no .net version setting in the properties.

Comment: Does those references works fine in the debug mode, but failed in the release mode? Not the xamarin android experts, for the .NET version, It`s seems that can not be modify in the properties except when create the xamarin android project. You can try to create  a demo with different .NET version, add those references, then verify this issue.